# Reasons for delegating bean registration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-autoconfiguration

I had a question while writing to test auto-configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class SimpleConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public BigDecimal aDecimal( String example ) {
        return new BigDecimal( example );
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class BigDecimal {
    
}
```

I think the above two codes have the same result of registering BigDecimal object as bean.
However, if you look at the example of auto-configuration, it is implemented with the code above.
Why use the code above if the two results are the same

Comment: The second should be `@Component public class BigDecimal {}` (but `@Configuration` itself is meta-annotated with `@Component`, so it would still "work").

Answer (score 0):

The first form gives you much more flexibility:

- Default parameter values
- Multiple bean instances of the same type
- Wiring (private) dependencies that are not beans themselves
- Registering classes as beans without touching those classes (you might not have access to the classes' source code, external libraries, etc.)